# how to add css class and Id to js variable

Tags: javascript, html, class, variables, createelement

```
let example  = document.createElement("p");
```

and now I want to add a new class to the p (<p>) that I just created.

Comment: example.classList.add("myClass");

Comment: example.id="myID";

Comment: ...or `example.className = "anyClass"`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `classList` and `id` properties of the element.

```
let example  = document.createElement("p");
example.id = "newid";
example.classList.add("newclass");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way:

```
// create node
const node = document.createElement('p');
// add id
node.setAttribute('id','new_id');
// add class
node.setAttribute('class', 'new-class');
```

Comment: did you mean node.setAttribute?

Comment: Thanks @AmirShiffer. I've edited the answer now. Accept it if this suits your requirement.

Comment: great, thanks you’ve helped me a lot